# Xdocument parse file and read values

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I have the below sample XML  , I  need to retrive the values for the following two fields txJu and ddate.I also have the code but it is giving null expection

```
<Doc id="580171" ddate="2019-06-21" >                       
    <ref dtRef="2019-08-21">                    
        <dr>                
            <cr>            
                <pj>        
                    <pr>    
                        <dDup txJu="0.00" txFi="0.00" txcOp="0.00" />
                        <comp txJu="12.96" txFi="2.45" txOp="0.00" />
                    </pr>   
                </pj>       
            </cr>           
        </dr>               
    </ref>                  
</Doc>  





  var xdoc = XDocument.Load(file);
   string txJu = xdoc.Root.Element("comp").Attribute("txJu").Value;
   string ddate = xdoc.Root.Element("Doc").Attribute("ddate").Value;
```

Comment: Root doesn't have `comp` element

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - can you help me how to get those values then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code. Your `Root` element doesn't contain `comp` node, `Doc` element is root itself, `string ddate = string value = ...` is invalid C# declaration. 
You can modify your code per following

```cs
var compElement = xdoc.Root?.DescendantsAndSelf("comp").FirstOrDefault();
string txJu = compElement?.Attribute("txJu")?.Value;
string ddate = xdoc.Root?.Attribute("ddate")?.Value;
string value = ddate;
```

Use [`DescendantsAndSelf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.descendantsandself?view=netframework-4.8) method to get a collection of filtered `comp` elements and use first of them. Access `ddate` attribute directly in `Root` element. Use [`null-conditional operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.descendantsandself?view=netframework-4.8) `?` to avoid possible null reference exceptions

Comment: I had the date statement wrong I fixed that in my question. Its getting me the date value fine but the txJu being returned as null.

Comment: I'm successfully getting `12.96` value using `DescendantsAndSelf` method